# MOTIS Object Mapping, With NSDictionary with values NSArray how can I specify type of array elements?

Tags: ios, objective-c, json

I have the json

> {"Types":{
>     "food":[{"cve":"1","description":"Pizza"},{"cve":"2","description":"Restaurant"},{"cve":"3","description":"Cafe"}],
>     "Health":[{"cve":"3","description":"Pharmacy"},{"cve":"4","description":"Hospital"}]
>     } }

Types.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface Types: NSObject
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSDictionary *types;

@end
```

Types.m

```
#import "Types.h"
#import <Motis/Motis.h>
#import "SubTipo.h"

@implementation Types
+ (NSDictionary*)mts_mapping
{
    return @{@"types": mts_key(types),};
}



@end
```

Subtype.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface Subtype: NSObject
@property (nonatomic, assign) int cve;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *description;
@end
```

Subtype.m

```
#import "Subtype.h"
#import <Motis/Motis.h>

@implementation Subtype
+ (NSDictionary*)mts_mapping
{
    return @{@"cve": mts_key(cve),
             @"description": mts_key(description),
             };
}

@end
```

I deserialize with

```
Types * values=[[Types alloc]init];
 NSDictionary * jsonObject = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:&error];


    [values mts_setValuesForKeysWithDictionary:jsonObject ];
```

I get NSDictionary with NSArray of  NSDictionary

but I need  NSDictionary  with NSArray of Subtypes

I try with

```
+ (NSDictionary*)mts_arrayClassMapping
{
    return @{mts_key(types): Subtype.class};
}
```

but wasn't successful

How can I get these with Motis

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As far as I see, your `Types` object is not properly defined. If you have an attribute of type **`NSDictionary*`** and the JSON received is a Dictionary, Motis won't perform any automatic conversion as the types already match (you are receiving a dictionary and your attribute is of type NSDictionary).

Therefore, you must implement your **`Type`** object following your JSON structure. This means that your `Type` object must have two properties of type array, one for `food` and one for `health`. Then, using the method **`+mts_arrayClassMapping`** you can specify the content type of the arrays to `Subtype`.

Here the implementation:

```
// ***** Type.h file ***** //

@interface Type: NSObject

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *food;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *health;

@end

// ***** Type.m file ***** //

@implementation Type

+ (NSDictionary*)mts_mapping
{
    return @{@"food": mts_key(food),
             @"Health": mts_key(health),
            };
}

+ (NSDictionary*)mts_arrayClassMapping
{
    return @{mts_key(food): Subtype.class,
             mts_key(health): Subtype.class,
            };
}

@end
```

Regarding the implementation of `Subtype`, yours is already correct. However, you should not use the property name `description` as it is already being used by `NSObject`:

```
// ***** Subtype.h file ***** //

@interface Subtype: NSObject

@property (nonatomic, assign) NSInteger cve;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *theDescription;

@end

// ***** Subtypes.m file ***** //

@implementation Subtype

+ (NSDictionary*)mts_mapping
{
    return @{@"cve": mts_key(cve),
             @"description": mts_key(theDescription),
             };
}

@end
```

Finally, as you list above, you can map your JSON, but first you will have to extract the "dictionary" for key Types, which you will map to your "Type" model object.

```
// Get the json data
NSDictionary * jsonObject = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:&error];

// Extract the JSON dictionary of types.
NSDictionary *jsonType = [jsonObject objectForKey:@"Types"];

// Create a Type object 
Type *type = [[Type alloc] init];

// Map JSON contents to the type object with Motis
[type mts_setValuesForKeysWithDictionary:jsonType];
```

Hoping this fixes your issue.